# In matplotlib plot cell averages instead of line plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Given a set of n 'co-ordinates', say `x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` and n-1 'values' `y = [10, 20, 30, 40]` I want to plot a piecewise-constant function which is equal to 10 for 0 < x <1, equal to 20 for 1 < x < 2 etc.

In other words, the x-list contains co-ordinates of cells boundaries while y-list represents value of this function inside cells. What is the standard way to plot such data?

I am also interested in non-regular grids and 2d plots.

Answer (score 2):

For the 1d data, you could use a bar plot. The first argument is the center of the bars, and the second their height.

```
x=np.asarray([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
centers=(x[1:]+x[:-1])/2.0
plt.bar(centers,[10, 20, 30, 40],width=1)
```

[image: barplot]

For 2d data, you can use [`pcolor`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=pcolor#matplotlib.pyplot.pcolor) and `colorbar`

```
# x coordinates of the cells
x=np.asarray([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
# y coordinates of the cells
y=np.asarray([0,1,2])
# values inside the cells
c = np.asarray([[10, 20, 30, 40], [50,60,70,80]])

# plot the cells
plt.pcolor(x,y,c)
# plot a bar to match colors with values
plt.colorbar()
```

[image: pcolor]

To plot non regular grids, `pcolor` can take as arguments 2d arrays for x and y: you can specify the x and y coordinates for each cell.
Note that `pcolormesh` plots the same thing than `pcolor` but much faster, which can be useful.